# Do i need to get API Token to get JSON Data from Jetpack API?

Tags: ios, json, wordpress, jetpack

My Website using `Jetpack` `JSON` Plugin to get `JSON` Data that want to use in iOS Apps.

Now i can access my website JSON data and can develop iOS App without `OAuth Authentication` with following `URL`.

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.mywebsite.com/posts/
```

Now i read documentation about these API , i see `OAuth2 Authentication` for API.

My Apps is using JSON Data to show only.

I want to know do i really need to do `OAuth2 Authentication` to use JSON Data?

Comment: put this url into web browser what you get ?

Comment: I can get JSON and can develop with that url. I just want to know do i need to create API Token , Key?

Comment: Now i can develop without that requirement.

Comment: Here is the thing, if you put this url in web browser and you get Json string then you don't need authentication, but if you get authentication error message then you need to authenticate.

Comment: ok thz. So i don't need it becaz i can get JSON String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so diving into the documentation I see this

> Before you begin to develop an application, you will need a client id
>   and a client secret key. The client id and client secret key will be
>   used to authenticate your application and verify that the API calls
>   being are valid. You can sign up for an id and secret at our

So basically you need to authenticate with JetPack. Here is the link: http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/

**If you want to know whether the api requires authentication or not then you just put the url in web browser, then if you get the json string, means no OAuth required, otherwise, you need to authenticate.**